# Four roots of the polynomial $x^4+px^3​+qx^2​+rx+1$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots

Let $a, b, c, d$ be four roots of the polynomial $x^4+px^3​+qx^2​+rx+1$ prove that $(a^4​+1)(b^4​+1)(c^4​+1)(d^4​+1)=(p^2​+r^2)​^2​+q^4-4pq^2​r$

Please provide hint.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @CalvinLin sorry my bad. I have edited it now. Though this might make it a little uglier than I thought it to be initially.

Comment: Hint: $(a^4 + 1) = (a - \omega)(a - \omega^3)(a - \omega^5)(a - \omega^7)$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{i \pi}{4}}$ and $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Expand all the terms in a similar manner and use $f(x) = x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + rx + 1 = (x - a)(x - b)(x-c)(x-d)$ to write the product as $f(\omega)f(\omega^3) f(\omega^5) f(\omega^7)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Done. Thanks for pointing it out. Do you know of a better way of solving it?

Comment: Nope. That and Yves' are the standard approaches that I take, but both are ugly. The next would be to find a quartic whose roots are $a^4$ and find $g(-1)$, but that's not that nice either.

Comment: Let's denote this polynomial by $f(x)$. Then $f(x)f(-x)$ is an even function, so we have a quartic polynomial $g(x)$ such that $$g(x^2)=f(x)f(-x).$$ It follows that the zeros of $g(x)$ are the squares of the zeros of $f(x)$. Do this again to get a polynomial with zeros that are the fourth powers of those of $f(x)$. Then apply @Calvin's idea.

Comment: If $p=r=0$ and $q=2$, I get $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+1=(x^2+1)^2$, so that $a,b=i$ and $c,d=-i$, and thus$(a^4+1)(b^4+1)(c^4+1)(d^4+1)=2^4=16$, but $(p^2+q^2)^2+q^4-4pq^2r=16+16-0=32$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615742/if-a-b-c-be-roots-of-2x3x2x-1-0-show-that-some-expression-is-equal-to-16/3615832#3615832

Comment: @Dhrdz Eartep Show please your attempts, otherwise this beautiful topic will be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

- $f(x) = x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + rx + 1$.
- $\Lambda = \{ a, b, c, d \}$ be the set of roots of $f(x)$.
- $\Omega = \left\{ \frac{\pm 1 \pm i}{\sqrt{2}} \right\}$ be the set of roots of $x^4 + 1$.

We have

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{P}\stackrel{def}{=}\prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda}(\lambda^4 + 1)
&= \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda}\prod_{\omega \in \Omega}(\lambda - \omega)
= \prod_{\omega \in \Omega}\prod_{\lambda _in \Lambda}(\omega - \lambda)
= \prod_{\omega \in \Omega}f(\omega)\\
&= \prod_{\omega \in \Omega}(p \omega^3 + q \omega^2 + r\omega)
\end{align}
$$
Since $\prod_{\omega \in \Omega} \omega^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$ and $\omega^{-1} = \bar{\omega}$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{P} = & \prod_{\omega \in \Omega}(q + p \omega + r \bar\omega)\\
= & \phantom{+}
\left(q + \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(p + r) + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(p - r)\right)
\left(q + \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(p + r) - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(p - r)\right)\\
& \times 
\left(q - \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(p + r) + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(p - r)\right)
\left(q - \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(p + r) - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(p - r)\right)\\
= & \left(q^2 + p^2 + r^2 + \sqrt{2}q(p+r)\right)
\left(q^2 + p^2 + r^2 - \sqrt{2}q(p+r)\right)\\
= & (q^2 + p^2 + r^2)^2 - 2q^2(p+r)^2\\
= & (p^2 + \color{red}{r}^2)^2 + q^4 - 4q^2 pr
\end{align}$$

<strike>Please note that there is a typo in the formula you want to prove.</strike>

Comment: oh sorry there is a typo.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: Very nice way of dealing with $\mathcal{P}$, making repeated use of the conjugates.

Answer (score 3):

We seek a quartic whose roots are $a^4, b^4, c^4 , d^4$.
Naively, this is $ x + px^{3/4} + qx^{1/2} + rx^{1/4} + 1 = 0 $, but the powers need to be integers.
Shifting terms, $x + qx^{1/2} + 1 = - px^{3/4} - rx^{1/4}$.
Squaring both sides, $x^2 + q^2x + 1 + 2x + 2qx^{3/2} + 2qx^{1/2} = p^2 x^{3/2} + 2pr x + r^2 x^{1/2}$.
Shifting terms, $x^2 + (q^2 - 2pr +2)x + 1 = x^{1/2} ((p^2-2q)x + (r^2 -2q))$.
Squaring again, $x^4 + (q^2 - 2pr +2)^2x^2 + 1 + 2(q^2 - 2pr +2)x^3 + 2(q^2 - 2pr +2)x + 2x^2 = x(  (p^2-2q)^2x^2 + (r^2 -2q)^2 + 2(p^2-2q)(r^2 -2q)x)$

Let

$$ g(x) = x^4 + (q^2 - 2pr +2)^2x^2 + 1 + 2(q^2 - 2pr +2)x^3 + 2(q^2 - 2pr +2)x + 2x^2 - x(  (p^2-2q)^2x^2 + (r^2 -2q)^2 + 2(p^2-2q)(r^2 -2q)x).$$

Then $g(x) = ( x - a^4)(x-b^4)(x-c^4)(x-^4)$,
so $g(-1) = \prod ( -1 - a^4) = \prod (a^4 + 1) $.
On the other hand, by substituting in $ x = -1$,
$ g(-1) = 1 + (q^2 - 2pr +2)^2 + 1 - 2(q^2 - 2pr +2) - 2(q^2 - 2pr +2) + 2 + (  (p^2-2q)^2 + (r^2 -2q)^2 - 2(p^2-2q)(r^2 -2q))$
$ = p^4 + 2p^2r^2 + r^4 + q^4 - 4pq^2 r $ (E.g. expand by [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+1+%2B+%28q%5E2+-+2pr+%2B2%29%5E2+%2B+1+-+2%28q%5E2+-+2pr+%2B2%29+-+2%28q%5E2+-+2pr+%2B2%29+%2B+2+%2B+%28++%28p%5E2-2q%29%5E2+%2B+%28r%5E2+-2q%29%5E2+-+2%28p%5E2-2q%29%28r%5E2+-2q%29%29))
which is the form that you want.

Comment: I used essentially the same trick but organized differently to work without fractional powers. Anyway, this is a well known trick. I actually learned about it when studying error-correcting codes with alphabet $\Bbb{Z}_4$. It's nice how these tricks pop up here and there.

Comment: They are essentially the same (our coefficients match, but I'm lazy to expand). I mentally didn't want to expand $f(x) f(-x)$ (25 terms, ugh). Of course, looking at this, what we're both doing is the "(even powers + odd powers ) ( even powers - odd powers ) = even powers ^2 - odd powers ^2 ".

Comment: Indeed. That's what I meant by "organizing it differently". Expanding those by hand would be a bit unpleasant, but less unpleasant than running the algorithm with elementary symmetric polynomials :-)

Answer (score 3):

I use the following trick.

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then $f(x)f(-x)$ is a polynomial with only even degree terms, so there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ such that 
>   $$g(x^2)=f(x)f(-x).$$ Then the zeros of $g(x)$ are exactly the squares of the zeros of $f(x)$.

With $f(x)=x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+1$ we arrive at
$$
g(x)=1 + (2 q - r^2) x + (2 + q^2 - 2 p r) x^2 + (-p^2 + 2 q) x^3 + x^4.
$$
Repeating the dose we look for a polynomial $h(x)$ such that $h(x^2)=g(x)g(-x)$.
Expanding gives us
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(x)&=1 + (4 - 2 q^2 - 4 p r + 4 q r^2 - r^4) x\\
& + (6 + 4 p^2 q - 4 q^2 + 
    q^4 - 8 p r - 4 p q^2 r + 2 p^2 r^2 + 4 q r^2) x^2\\
& + (4 - p^4 + 
    4 p^2 q - 2 q^2 - 4 p r) x^3 + x^4.
\end{aligned}
$$
As explained in the comments, because
$$
h(x)=(x-a^4)(x-b^4)(x-c^4)(x-d^4)
$$ the answer is
$$
h(-1)=p^4+2 p^2 r^2-4 p q^2 r+q^4+r^4.
$$

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the fact that

$$x^4+1=-(px^2+qx+r)x,$$

expand the product and substitute Vieta's expressions.

Comment: While I agree that has to work, I seems like it's going to be pretty ugly.

Comment: @CalvinLin: that's right, there will be $81$ terms. There must be an extra shortcut.

Comment: In the expansion, I get an $r^4$ term (like you can see in yours), which doesn't appear in the RHS, so I'm wondering if there is more cancellation that is going on.

Comment: @CalvinLin: indeed, this is strange. If $p=q=0$, we should get $r^4$.

Comment: @CalvinLin (and Yves), please see my comment below the OP. Something seems wrong in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

$$\prod_{cyc}(a^4+1)=((a^2b^2-1)^2+(a^2+b^2)^2)((c^2d^2-1)^2+(c^2+d^2)^2)=$$
$$=((a^2b^2-1)(c^2+d^2)+(c^2d^2-1)(a^2+b^2))^2+$$
$$+((a^2b^2-1)(c^2d^2-1)-(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2))^2=$$
$$=\left(\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2c^2-\sum_{cyc}a^2\right)^2+\left(a^2b^2c^2d^2-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{sym}a^2b^2\right)^2.$$
Can you end it now?